# How to programmatically find out (using Node) how a given string would be rendered in browser?

Tags: html, node.js, dom, browser, whitespace

How do you get the string that browser rendered, programmatically, using Node/JS — the same thing as if you copied everything in a browser window?

For example, for this given HTML source (notice spaces between "a" and "z"):

`<html><head></head><body>a         z</body>`

which renders with a single space in Chrome:

[image]

how would you get this string with single space, `a z`?

I tried Cheerio and JSDom, but after I load the `<html><head></head><body>a         z</body>` as string and query the `body` contents, I get original piece of code back, the one with many spaces.

Thank you.

Comment: This might be one of the few uses for `innerText`, which returns `a z` in-browser

Comment: @CertainPerformance Seems legit to me. Consider providing it as an answer.

Comment: @estus I don't know how to implement it in a Node DOM parser (never used them myself), and for some reason I can't even get it to work with `DOMParser` in-browser, so I figured I'd just comment

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, isn't supported in JSDOM, https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1245 . I guess the best bet is to use headless browser if it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, however I don't think that there will be feasible way to do it.

First, what is happening is greatly explained in this article [When does white space matter in HTML?](https://medium.com/@patrickbrosset/when-does-white-space-matter-in-html-b90e8a7cdd33).

Since white spaces are not going anywhere, but represented in such way only by browser, it will hard to troubleshoot it server side. There are reasons for that:

- You don't know in which browser it will be rendered, it could be even `Lynx`, will it show spaces or not you don't know.
- That means that, if it would be possible, you would have to test with every browser in the wild.
- For instance Server-Side-Rendering (SSR) technology, partially applies / renders pages on server side, but still because there is no actually a device that will display it, it is partial. So most likely you will get same spaces.

Imaginary possible solution would be to use something like KarmaJS, install some headless browser on server side, and execute some test cases, so that KarmaJS would control browser to render the page, and may be you will be able to get access to rendered, CSS applied and hopefully spaces-trimmed DOM. Which I'm not sure, and it will be limited set of browsers.

Another imaginary possible solution would be to use WebKit or Blink engines, or perhaps Electron, to some how via API attempt to acquire that DOM.